# How do I specify that a file extension needs to be run with a switch?

Tags: windows-8.1, file-association, file-extension

I would like to make certain open with a specific program, but that program requires a specific switch to be provided for it to actually open it.  How would I go about setting this up?

The specific case here is me trying to use the 1964 emulator, which requires the file to be opened to have a `-g` before hand.  For example, like this: `1964.exe -g "C:\Path\To\Rom.n64"`.  It doesn't accept `1964.exe "C:\Path\To\Rom.n64"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a batch file with the specific arguments and associate the extension to it.

1. Create a batch file in C:\temp\1964.cmd with the content:

   C:\Path\To\1964.exe -g %1
2. Right click and *.n64, open with -> Choose default program, and pick C:\temp\1964.cmd

Comment: It's not remembering the choice...  Whenever I select it, it opens fine, but then double clicking it again does nothing.  (For the record, rather than having `open` and `open with`, it just as `open with...` -- I think it hasn't had any extensions registered and won't behave right.  I've tried both `.bat` and `.cmd`)

Comment: ... After setting it to open incorrectly with `1964.exe` (intentionally), I was able to register it properly.  Weird.  I noticed that in the registry (was poking around to see if I could do stuff there), the stuff in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.n64\OpenWithList` wasn't updating until I chose a `.exe` program, but once I did it allowed the `.bat` one to work fine and was updated with that as well.

Comment: Weird. I did test with *.abc and it worked.Maybe some settings mess up from before. Glad to know it worked for you :)